# Android Studio Top-5 Score table concern

Tags: android

[image]

I seem to have a problem occurring with my top-5 scoreboard table. I know there are many ways to solve this problem or to have a proper scoreboard but this is my first one and the problem that occur seems to stem from when;

i score 120 or higher it will then take fourth place and fifth place will correctly take 110. but if a game is to score under the Fourth or fifth recorded top score this glitch occurs showing a high score in the 5th spot.

i provided some code on how i went about taking the top 5 scores. if anyone knows where i went wrong in my code specific i would appreciate another set of eyes to scan over it.

```
    if(lastScore > best5) {
        best5 = lastScore;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("best5", best5);
        editor.apply();
    }
    if(lastScore > best4) {
        int temp = best4;
        best4 = lastScore;
        best5 = temp;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("best5 ", best5);
        editor.putInt("best4", best4);
        editor.apply();
    }
    if(lastScore > best3) {
        int temp = best3;
        best3 = lastScore;
        best4 = temp;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("best4", best4);
        editor.putInt("best3 ", best3);
        editor.apply();
    }
    if(lastScore > best2) {
        int temp = best2;
        best2 = lastScore;
        best3 = temp;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("best3", best3);
        editor.putInt("best2", best2);
        editor.apply();
    }
    if(lastScore > best1) {
        int temp = best1;
        best1 = lastScore;
        best2 = temp;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("best2", best2);
        editor.putInt("best1", best1);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you store them into a list, sort them from greatest to least, then take the first 5 elements in the list?

Comment: save them on sqlite database so you can easily sort them